# Dart find the capital word in a given String

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I write a code that finds capital words in a given string in dart

for example

```
String name ='deryaKimlonLeo'
//output='KL'
```

Comment: var string = "Pub";string.split(""); give a list like ["P", "u", "b"] . So use a for loop to get what you want

Comment: try using pattern if you don't want to do loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample code:

```dart
void main() {
  String test = "SDFSDdsfdDFDS";
  for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    if (test[i].compareTo('A') >= 0  && test[i].compareTo('Z') <= 0)
      print(test[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: good method can you explain a little more

Comment: according to compareTo documentation: 
"Compares this string to other. Returns a negative value if this is ordered before other, a positive value if this is ordered after other, or zero if this and other are equivalent." so you can check if a character is between A and Z so the character is capital.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm try this using pattern if you only want to get only the big letter then try this

```
String name ='deryaKimlonLeo';
print(name.replaceAll(RegExp(r'[a-z]'),""));

//Output you wanted will be 
// KL
```

try this on dart pad it works

Comment: thanks how do you know which regs method do you use?

Answer (score 2):

A basic way of doing this is like

```dart
void main() {
  String name = 'deryaKimlonLeo';

  String result = '';
  for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name.codeUnitAt(i) <= 90 && name.codeUnitAt(i) >= 65) {
      result += name[i];
    }
  }

  print(result);
}
```

More about [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) and [codeUnitAt](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.15.1/dart-core/String/codeUnitAt.html).

Comment: can you axplain a little codeunit<=90 and <=65

Comment: `A`  ASCII value is 65 and `90` for `Z`, you can find more on  attached link .

Comment: thankyou so much